# Multiple user classes in Parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Is it possible to create different `ParseUser` implementations, each one with its own fields? For example, we have a `Student` and a `Company` classes extending `ParseUser` and we want to separate the Student's specific fields from Company's ones, but when I try to persist a new Student or a new Company it will work only if both student and company's specific fields are modeled inside _User class.
Can I have two custom objects, extending the `ParseUser` class in order to make them able to use the built-in Login function?

Comment: Have you tried creating two User classes in the data browser?

Comment: I cannot create more than one User class; only custom classes can be created more times. The only solution, I think, is to create student and company as custom classes and implementing login on my own. Any idea about how to avoid it??

Comment: its not a good solution but since parse is using mangodb/JSON style storage, you can just add all the specific columns to User and in your code you can query select what you actually need. You won't use extra storage it'll only be less human readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about three tables, User, Student, and Company.  Student and Company each have a pointer to User.  That allows you to use parse authentication, and separate the different types of data, at the expense of complicating the queries somewhat.  If you don't want to do that, Thellimist's solution will also work.